# PHP email issue

Tags: php, mysql

I've a HTML signup form with php. After a successfully submit it sends a confirmation email to the user email address.

Well, when user see his/her email it's shown as:

```
Yoursite.comr@mediaplan.ovh.net
```

But I didn't  add the *@mediaplan.ovh.net* part to the email address. Why it's showing in this address. *@mediaplan.ovh.net*? and how do i remove it?

**php email code:**

```
$to = "$email";                     
$subject = "Signup | Verification";
$message = "Congratulation $f_name $l_name you have been successfully registered. 
Please click the link to active your account.\r\n";
$message .= "http://www.maaks.fr/hotel/verify.php?email=$email&hash=$hash\r\n";

$from = "Yoursite.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-rype: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding; 7bit\r\n";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "r\n";

$mailsent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: not enough details to debug what is $from content ?

Comment: You didn't use a valid [email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) for `from`, perhaps `sendmail` automatically append the server's hostname.

Comment: I wish someone would go through all these old forums and crappy tutorials on PHP mail() and just delete them off the internet forever.

Comment: You might have more luck using a pre-written library specifically for sending emails like http://swiftmailer.org/ - You'll also want to add another "\" before the r on the from line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You are missing a slash in your *from* header part.

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "r\n";
                          //  ^ Here
```

Change `From` headers while sending the mail

```
$from = "WebsiteName <Your@mail.com>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-rype: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding; 7bit\r\n";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
```

Comment: @Starx It's show noreply@yoursite.com via 57.mail-out.ovh.net

Comment: @user1802398 that is totally normal if you uses a shared hosting. Your mail is sent through that server.

Comment: It seems shared Hosting Cpanel are configured that way. Check [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/php-mail-sent-via-hostname-247581.html)

Comment: @user1802398, Ok, You haven't provided a valid email address. Use a valid user name, look at my answer once again. Use something `Automated Response <info@yoursite.com>`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing $from to email address.

```
$from = "noreply@yoursite.com";
```